# Reading and writing to a collection

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following class:

```
public class GroupsContainer{

    private final List<Group> col;

    public synchronized Group get(int ids){
            return col.get(ids);
    }

    public synchronized void add(Group g){
            col.add(g);
    }
}
```

Now suppose some thread wanted to get all elements from 0 to 10:

```
List<Group> lst;
GroupContainer gc;
//staff
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    lst.add(gc.get(i));
```

and at the same time another thread is trying to write new elements from 0 to 10:

```
List<Group> lst;
GroupContainer gc;
//staff
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    gc.add(i, lst.get(i));
```

I need to do the following:

Once the writer release the monitor, the reader should block all writer's thread right after that and shouldn't allow writer to write something else until it's finished with reading.

Is it possible to do? With the current implementation it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your method is synchronized, but you want to synchronize several invocations of them (10 in your example). you could simply wrap your code in a synchronized block:

```
 synchronized(gc){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        lst.add(gc.get(i));
}
```

Comment: But the reader and the writer are probably indtances of the different classes.

Comment: So? If you synchronize on the same instance of GroupContainer, the lock is the GroupContainer, not the calling class.

Comment: If this is the standard readers/writers problem, this solution won't work. It wouldn't allow two threads to read simultaneously.

Comment: But is it realible the if there's a reader waiting for the monitor to be released and a writer owning the monitor, after the writer releases it the reader should acquire it right away? I mean can writer acquire the same monitor one more time while writing in a loop?

Comment: @jbkm So, what would be the solution?

Comment: take a look at the link Pshemo shared in a comment off of your question. That looks like something you could make use of.